# A problem with designing a time register

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, register, time

I'm on a project where I need to design a time difference register. In a time register the time information is first converted to voltage, which is stored in a capacitor. Later, when we want the register to output, we use this voltage to generate two signals whose timing information is the same as the input signals'.

The circuit below is part of the TR circuit,  where the bottom inverter is supposed to produce a low-to-high signal as soon as the voltage across the capacitor discharges to exactly 0V (a full discharge of Vc), and the top inverter is supposed to produce another low-to-high signal right at the time the capacitor starts to discharge (or when a RegOUT signal arrives).

[image]

The circuitry that charges C is not shown in the image. At the falling edge of the controlling signal RegOUT the capacitor starts to discharge through the resistor R. In order for the time register to give a correct output the capacitor must discharge fully before M1 turns on. I cannot directly connect the analog RC circuit to the inverter, since when Vc=0V M1 has already turned on, which produces an earlier signal at the output. This causes some of the information stored as voltage to be lost. Therefore we need to keep M1 off for as long as it takes for the capacitor voltage to drop to 0V. But how?

Note that I do not want to use a comparator to switch M1. I want to use as fewer transistors as possible to implement the function. Any idea is very welcoming!

Comment: You may want to research designs for "time-to-digital converters."

Comment: This screams "MCU" - it is trying to make discrete analog solutions work which will cause complexity.  This "use as few transistors" is evidence that you do not know what you are doing.  At the least, a comparator in a tiny package would help with the size and board complexity.  And no, asking people here to design it for you doesn't count as doing it yourself (if that was your justification for making illogical technology choices)

Comment: @Justin Interestingly this is part of an integrated-circuit TDC design project where I use this time register to implement a SAR TDC

Comment: Instead of requiring that "the capacitor must discharge fully before M1 turns on," why not choose a threshold that is more easily attainable. Theoretically, it will take infinite time to reach 0V ignoring noise. Do you really want your timing to be based on noise?

Comment: You could perhaps create a configurable threshold using perhaps a strongly-offset inverter, either configurable using a switched resistive divider, switched transistors in the inverter, or maybe running off a variable/starved supply. As Chris said, minimizing transistors is a very strange requirement for an IC design. I could see minimizing area, but not minimizing transistors.

Comment: In any case, I think the problem is still far too open as you've defined it here. It's suitable for a semester research project, but unfortunately not for a StackExchange Q/A.

Comment: @Justin By fewer transistors I meant little area, and less power consumption, since this project is aimed at IoT applications. And yes, I was a bit off being precise on the 0V line, not exactly 0V but close enough is good.

Comment: @Justin Thanks for your cool ideas, a strongly offset inverter sounds a nice one.